# Good workflow with emacs+swank+slime+clojure?

Tags: emacs, clojure, swank

I just wanted opinion on good workflow using the emacs environment with clojure+swank+slime. I often find myself doing very repetitive keycommands and wonder if there is an obvious better way.

I include swank with lein and start my project using lein swank from shell. Then I connect with emacs and do the correct use commands so that I can start to use (run-tests ). Then I do some coding and then want to test.

To run the test I need to change buffer in emacs to the swank-repl C-x o, then I need to go to the prompt M->, then repeat the command M-p, then enter, maybe with an exception, then back to the code buffer and continue all over again with all the emacs commands. I find it a bit repetitive.

I guess the solution would be to start hack on emacs and maybe add a shortcut for doing this repetitive task, but I would love to hear some suggestions because I can't be the only one who find this tedious?

Comment: This question has been asked many times - here's the most recent duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984146/efficient-clojure-workflow

Comment: Thanks, found a couple of interesting tips there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The clojure-test mode allows almost instantaneous test-edit-test :

- C-c t    : will swap between test code and the implementation code
- C-c C-,  : runs the tests and highlights the line with the failing error
- C-c C-l  : reloads the current file after an edit

For this to work, your tests must follow a convention :

src/name/space/file_under_test.clj

and the testcases in

test/name/space/test/file_under_test.clj

Comment: Thanks Peter. I will give that one a try.

Comment: Managed to get it up and running and this was definitive a step forward. Once again thanks!

Comment: For me this is C-c C-t.